# Subscriber callback in class defined as shared_ptr

Tags: ros, shared-ptr, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have very weird problem. I'm trying to set callback function to one of my subscribers. The problem is that the object, in which the callback function is declared, is defined as `std::shared_ptr`. Let me give you an example. Assume we have 2 classes, class **A** and **B**.

Class **A** looks like this:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>

class A {
public:
    A(const ros::NodeHandle& nh) : nh_(nh), subscriber_(nh_.subscribe("topic", 10, &B::callback, b_.get())){
        b_ = std::make_shared<B>(nh_);    
    }

private:
    ros::NodeHandle nh_;
    ros::Subscriber subscriber_;    

    std::shared_ptr<B> b_;
};
```

And class **B** looks like this:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/PoseStamped.h>

class B {
public:
    B(const ros::NodeHandle& nh) : nh_(nh) {}

    callback(const geometry_msgs::PoseStampedConstPtr& pose){
        value_ = 1.0;
    }
private:
   double value_{0.0};
};
```

And this obviously doesn't work for some reason. The strange thing is that I can only **ROS_INFO** the data coming to my topic in callback function, but not modify any member variables in class **B**. I think it has to do something with callback function looking at "wrong place". Normally I can modify member variables without problem.

Is there some solution to this? Is it even possible to point callback to function in class defined as `std::shared_ptr`?

Thank you for any advice.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262140/subscriber-callback-in-class-defined-as-shared_ptr/) by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 826 on 2017-05-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2017-05-19**:
Please post your compiler warnings/error or an example log. Do you have a spinner somewhere? See http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2017-05-23**:
Well I do have a spinner there, it would be impossible to ROS_INFO the callback function without it. There's no problem with compilation. It just crashes during runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I figured out the problem already. The problem was that firsly I initialized object **B** as **nullptr** which led to runtime error. After creating some pointer instead of nullptr, I was able to modify the member variables.

---

Originally posted by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) with karma: 826 on 2017-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0